# Javascript: innerHTML and <hr> tag in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

I have a problem in displaying an `<hr>` tag with IE, because when I use:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '&lt;hr&gt;';
```

IE says that there are errors in the page, but if I replace `&lt;hr&gt;` with some other HTML tags it works.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you please post the complete code? What exactly is the error you see and where do you see it. Please be specific so others can help.

Comment: Tried this fiddle in IE11, works perfect .. https://jsfiddle.net/oLLan9zj/

Comment: @KonstantinDinev http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp "In HTML, the <hr> tag has no end tag."

Comment: @KonstantinDinev In HTML it is not needed, for XHTML it is.

Comment: What is the error? Is it about character encoding?

Comment: @KonstantinDinev The <hr> tag is self closing but does not need a closing slash and never has. That's an XHTML/XML thing. Though not an error, it's ignored by browsers.